# Android Bluetooth String Receiver

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino

I hope you can help me getting this Bluetooth Receiver working correctly.
The String I'm going to receive is send by an Arduino Uno with an HC-06 Bluetooth module and I can receive it in several Bluetooth terminal apps.

The string I try to receive is like the following: `#id=3,temp=100,maxtemp=103,rpm=27,maxrpm=27*`

but I just receive data like this:

```
07-21 12:45:17.959  31174-31174/fabian.d.de.rc_telemetrie_test D/BT﹕ Empfangen: 4*
07-21 12:45:18.141  31174-31174/fabian.d.de.rc_telemetrie_test D/BT﹕ Empfangen: p=83maxtemp=149rpm=34maxrpm=34*
07-21 12:45:18.471  31174-31174/fabian.d.de.rc_telemetrie_test D/BT﹕ Empfangen: 34*
07-21 12:45:18.583  31174-31174/fabian.d.de.rc_telemetrie_test D/BT﹕ Empfangen: 2maxrpm=34*
07-21 12:45:18.761  31174-31174/fabian.d.de.rc_telemetrie_test D/BT﹕ Empfangen: 4*
07-21 12:45:18.911  31174-31174/fabian.d.de.rc_telemetrie_test D/BT﹕ Empfangen: 34*
07-21 12:45:19.237  31174-31174/fabian.d.de.rc_telemetrie_test D/BT﹕ Empfangen: m=17maxrpm=34*
07-21 12:45:19.388  31174-31174/fabian.d.de.rc_telemetrie_test D/BT﹕ Empfangen: =29maxrpm=34*
```

Here is my Bluetooth Handler. I hope you can help me finding the issue.

```
bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == handlerState) {
            String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;
            recDataString.append(readMessage);
            int endOfLineIndex = recDataString.indexOf("*");
            if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {
                String dataInPrint = recDataString.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);
                txtString.setText("Daten Empfangen: = " + dataInPrint);
                int dataLength = dataInPrint.length();
                txtStringLength.setText("Datenlänge: = " + String.valueOf(dataLength));

                Log.d("BT", "Received: " + recDataString);
                if (recDataString.charAt(0) == '#')
                {
                    Log.d("BT", "Matching string received: " + recDataString);
                    String[] parts = recDataString.split(",");
                    for (String part : parts) {
                        if (part.startsWith("temp=")) {
                            strTemp = part;
                            strTemp = strTemp.substring(5);
                        }
                        else if (part.startsWith("maxtemp=")) {
                            strMaxtemp = part;
                            strMaxtemp = strMaxtemp.substring(8);
                        }
                        else if (part.startsWith("rpm=")) {
                            strRpm = part;
                            strRpm = strRpm.substring(4);
                        }
                        else if (part.startsWith("maxrpm=")) {
                            strMaxrpm = part;
                            strMaxrpm = strMaxrpm.substring(7);
                        }
                    }
                    sensorView0.setText(" Temperatur: " + strTemp + "°C");  //update the textviews with sensor values
                    sensorView1.setText(" maximale Temperatur: " + strMaxtemp + "°C");
                    sensorView2.setText(" RPM: " + strRpm + "/min");
                    sensorView3.setText(" maximale RPM: " + strMaxrpm + "/min");
                }
                recDataString.delete(0, recDataString.length());                    //clear all string data
            }
        }
};
```

Edit: Here is my connect thread:

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    //creation of the connect thread
    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        try {
            //Create I/O streams for connection
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }


    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
        int bytes;

        // Keep looping to listen for received messages
        while (true) {
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);            //read bytes from input buffer
                String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity via handler
                bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //write method
    public void write(String input) {
        byte[] msgBuffer = input.getBytes();           //converts entered String into bytes
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);                //write bytes over BT connection via outstream
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //if you cannot write, close the application
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the code where data arriving over BT is being read through stream? This is where the message is passed to handler. In addition a look at the question and answer there in will help you to understand the issue being faced by you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156547/android-bluetooth-sending-concatenated-data-at-once/31187882#31187882

Comment: I've added the code you mean, hopefully anybody can find the issue there. Thank you for this link, but unfortunately I don't know what to do with that.

Comment: Just a couple of thoughts.. First of all I'd do `while ((endOfLineIndex= recDataString.indexOf("*")) > 0)` instead of `if (endOfLineIndex > 0)`; this way if you receive multiple packets you will manage to see them all. Moreover I'd replace `recDataString.delete(0, recDataString.length());` with `recDataString.delete(0, endOfLineIndex);`, so you won't remove unanalyzed data. Then instead of testing for `recDataString.charAt(0) == '#'` I'd remove all the chars until the first char is a `#` (or the string is empty. And for your problem... Maybe you have a race condition... Try to see if the

Comment: function is called twice before exiting (for instance put a `Log.d("Entered")` at the beginning of the `handleMessage` function and then a `Log.d("Exited")` at its end, then check if there are only enters followed by exits and no multiple enters...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your logic seems to be fine. The hints from [frarugi87](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3368201/frarugi87) may make it more stable.

While using the BlueToothChat example code in past I faced similar issue. The root cause identified was :

- The statement `bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);` is a blocking
  call. It returns to next line only after receiving some data over
  BlueTooth.
- The time between two consequetive returns is       unpredictable,
  and the count of characters returned each time are       also random.
- When such events are passed to handler, then the       speed of
  these events cannot be handled with same speed by UI thread.

The solution arrived was:

1. Do not send the string each time to the handler i.e. avoid sending strings after each blocking call return.
2. Instead, keep accumulating the incoming strings till complete packet is identified.
3. Pass only the complete packet to handler. This reduces the frequency of calling of UI thread.